# Gtk-WARNING ** Inhibit called with an unrealized window

Tags: bash, scripts

While setting up a script to run a slideshow in Bash, I ran into an annoying problem. The slideshow will run just fine, but in between pictures (or movies) it will display the desktop, and the screen will show the warning above. I'm not sure how to fix it; or why it's going on at all really.

The script i'm using to play the slideshow is pretty straight forward:

```
while true
do
for f in $FILES
do
filename=$(basename "$f")
extension="${filename##*.})"

 #shopt -s nocasematch

 if [ $extension == "mp4" ] || [ $extension == "mov" ]
mplayer $filename -fs

elif [ $extension == "jpg" ] 
timeout 5 /usr/bin/eog --fullscreen $filename

fi

done
done
```

Now i'm not sure what I did wrong, But this seems to be the only way I can logically think of writing this script. I tried looking up what the warning meant, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I'm not even necessarily looking to fix the issue, If there is a way to suppress the message from popping the screen out of the slideshow, I wouldn't mind just doing that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, your script **can't** work. Correct the errors below:

```
   1  while true
   2  do
   3  for f in $FILES
      ^––SC1009 The mentioned parser error was in this for loop.
   4  do
   5  filename=$(basename "$f")
   6  extension="${filename##*.})"
   7  
   8   #shopt -s nocasematch
   9  
  10   if [ $extension == "mp4" ] || [ $extension == "mov" ]
       ^––SC1049 Did you forget the 'then' for this 'if'?
       ^––SC1073 Couldn't parse this if expression.
  11  mplayer $filename -fs
  12  
  13  elif [ $extension == "jpg" ] 
      ^––SC1050 Expected 'then'.
           ^––SC1072 Expected "#". Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
  14  timeout 5 /usr/bin/eog --fullscreen $filename
  15  
  16  fi
  17  
  18  done
  19  done
```

---

*I have nothing improved or adapted to this script. Now it works technically. Whether your code is logically correct, you have to decide.*

Eg:

```
while true; do
  for f in $FILES; do
    filename=$(basename "$f")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    if [ "$extension" == "mp4" ] || [ "$extension" == "mov" ]; then
      mplayer "$filename" -fs
    elif [ "$extension" == "jpg" ]; then
      timeout 5 /usr/bin/eog --fullscreen "$filename"
    fi
  done
done
```

---

### Extra tip for the future:

Have your scripts checked [here](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, is there a way to keep the window from closing to the desktop each time it changes files? So it would seamlessly go from one to the next, without ruining the user's experience?

Comment: An answer to this question would be too long for a comment. You should ask a new question. Complete with your functioning script. **;)**

Comment: Done! Feel free to answer it if you're feeling extra helpful today! :D

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/647947/seamless-slideshow-transition-with-this-script  - Part 2