# Seamless slideshow transition with this script

Tags: scripts, slideshow

I am looking to make this script seamlessly change files without flashing to the desktop in the transition process. Whether It be just a blank black screen, or it fades in and out of files, I don't mind either way, just as long as the user's experience isn't interrupted in the process.

The script is as follows:

```sh
while true; do
  for f in $FILES; do
    filename=$(basename "$f")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    if [ "$extension" == "mp4" ] || [ "$extension" == "mov" ]; then
      mplayer "$filename" -fs
    elif [ "$extension" == "jpg" ]; then
      timeout 5 /usr/bin/eog --fullscreen "$filename"
    fi
  done
done
```

I'm not sure how I would go about this, I looked up ways to disable the desktop, but that didn't seem to fix my problem.